# How to cover a void method that avoids null parameters by passing a null parameter?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a method like this:

```
public class SomeService {
    public void sortByFieldX(List<MyClass> list) {
        if (list != null) {
            Collections.sort(list, new ComparatorOfMyClassThatUsesFieldX());
        }
    }
}
```

How should I write a test for `sortByFieldX` where I pass `null` argument?

```
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void sortByFieldX() {
        List<MyClass> list = null;
        SomeService service = new SomeService();
        service.sortByFieldX(list);
        //assert what?
        //assertNull(list); is really stupid because Java is pass by value
    }
}
```

Is this test even valid? I'm just trying to write this test as part of a set of tests to cover all the branches in code.

Comment: That seems sufficiently trivial as to not need testing. At the most, I'd suggest a test checking if a null-pointer exception occurs or not to cover any problems future changes might induce.

Comment: If you know the method should do _nothing_ when `null` is passed - check that. No `Exception` should be thrown. No other `class` state should be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a `null` argument the method does nothing - it doesn't modify any argument (since it's a `null`), it doesn't return anything (since its a `void` method), it doesn't update any data member or throw any exception.

IMHO, it's a bit pointless to test such a case, but if you want to be on the safe side, the only thing to test here is that a `null` input doesn't generate an exception (specifically, a `NullPointerException`). The test you've provided indeed achieves this goal. As you noted inline, asserting that `null` is in fact `null` is pointless.

EDIT:
As per Brois the Spider's suggestion in the comments, this behavior can be made more explicit by using the [`ExpectedException`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) rule:

```
public class SomeServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

    /** Just makes sure no exception is thrown */
    @Test
    public void sortByFieldX() {
        List<MyClass> list = null;
        SomeService service = new SomeService();
        service.sortByFieldX(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you could add [`ExpectedException.none()`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) to be explicit.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza IMHO, yes. Perhaps it's worth adding a comment explaining that all this test does is to assert no NPE is thrown, so a careless contributor in the future won't just remove it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider +1, nice suggestion.

Comment: Personally ExpectedException.none() is not necessary here as long as our test case have conveyed this msg explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

you can try add this attribute:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void sortByFieldX() {
        List<MyClass> list = null;
        SomeService service = new SomeService();
        service.sortByFieldX(list);
    }
```

Comment: So that's wrong for two reasons:  first, it's never going to throw the exception, which is what the test here is *looking* for to pass, and second, you should  never **expect** an NPE to be thrown.  Not unless you're throwing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**With JUnit parameters, you can describe a test suite with your expected conditions (whatever the given list, nullable or not):**

```
package foo.bar;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

/**
 * Use matrix of parameters and iterate over it to check all your conditions
 * with only one annonated method.
 *
 */
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @Parameter
    public boolean isNull;

    @Parameter(value = 1)
    public boolean isSorted;

    @Parameter(value = 2)
    public List<MyClass> list;

    private static List<MyClass> listToSort = Arrays.asList( //
            new MyClass("D"), //
            new MyClass("B"), //
            new MyClass("A"), //
            new MyClass("C"));

    /**
     * Put your conditions here.
     */
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> parameters() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { //
                { true, true, null }, // test 1
                        { false, true, listToSort } // test 2
                // test n ...
                });
    }

    private Comparator<MyClass> comparator = new ComparatorOfMyClassThatUsesFieldX();

    @Test
    public void sortByFieldX() {
        // Given
        SomeService service = new SomeService();

        // When
        service.sortByFieldX(list);

        // Then
        assertEquals(isNull, list == null);
        if (Optional.ofNullable(list).isPresent()) {
            assertEquals(isSorted, Ordering.from(comparator).isOrdered(list));
        }
    }
}
```

**The comparator :**

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class ComparatorOfMyClassThatUsesFieldX implements Comparator<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) {
        if (o1.getFieldX() == o2.getFieldX()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (o1.getFieldX() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o2.getFieldX() == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return o1.getFieldX().compareTo(o2.getFieldX());
    }
}
```

**If you can use Java 8, I suggest a "one-liner" to sort the list:**

```
private Comparator<MyClass> fieldComparator = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getFieldX);

/**
 * Check null > parallelization > sort.
 * 
 * @param list
 *            Nullable list to sort.
 */
public void sortByFieldX(List<MyClass> list) {
    Optional.ofNullable(list).ifPresent(l -> l.parallelStream().sorted(fieldComparator));
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but unit tests are to cover the current code and then improve it, not the other way around